# Get the right coordinates from shapefile with unknown SRC

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a a Point Shapefile with **unknown SRC**, however it's plotted correctly in space, ie. in the right place, along with other files in, my project which is using EPSG:4326.

If I try to set EPSG:4326 to the unknown SRC shapefile it'll be plotted in a different and incorrect place.

I need to get the current coordinates from the points (unknown SRC shapefile), meaning that the coordinates must be correctly where they're now.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: You could extract some coordinate pairs and try to find a CRS which they fit.

Comment: right click on your layer -> layer properties. The top entry is information. there you should find the CRS your layer is in?

Comment: @sn1ks The layer is currently projected as unknown SRC.

Comment: Exploring a little bit of the data, I think it's a mathematical issue. The right coordinates should be (40,-15), but when I extract the points coordinates the come as (40000,-150000). I'll try to solve this, and see what happens!

Comment: Then if they are in the right place that is the correct (but unrecognised) CRS - just leave it. If you need to convert them to 4326 then Save the layer as a new layer with EPSG:4326 set

Comment: @IanTurton thank you! It is exactly what I needed.